# Lotka-Volterra ordinary differential equation model to describe oscillations in a single observed entity

Tags: r, ecology, stan, dynamic-regression, differential-equations

#### Background

The [Lotka-Volterra model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lotka%E2%80%93Volterra_equations) is the starting point for any model of ecological dynamics. It can be described as a set of two ordinary differential equations (ODEs) with varying complexity. [McElreath (2019)](https://xcelab.net/rm/statistical-rethinking/) describes the simplest form (similar to the linked Wikipedia article) as $$\frac{dN_1}{dt}=N_1(\alpha-N_2\beta)$$ $$\frac{dN_2}{dt}=N_2(N_1\gamma-\delta)$$ where $N_1$ is the abundance of prey whose mortality $\beta$ is proportional to $N_2$, the abundance of predators, whose fecundity $\gamma$ in turn is proportional to $N_1$, the abundance of prey. [Breckling et al. (2011)](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-05029-9_6) improve this model without increasing the number of parameters, by recognising that $\beta$ and $\gamma$ are inherently the same parameter (hereinafter $\beta$) because mortality of prey and fecundity of predators are directly related by a new parameter $\epsilon$, the prey-to-predator conversion efficiency: $$\frac{dN_1}{dt}=N_1(\alpha-N_2\beta)$$ $$\frac{dN_2}{dt}=N_2(N_1\epsilon\beta-\delta)$$

#### Case | MRE

I have data on the activity of extracellular enzymes in environmental samples. The response variable `y` is substrate-saturated enzyme activity (micromoles of substrate per square centimetre per minute) and the predictor variable `x` is time (days). The data describe an oscillating trajectory such as that in this R simulation:

```
set.seed(123)
n <- 100
x <- seq(0, 10, length.out = n)
y <- exp(0.2 * x * sin(2 * x) + rnorm(n, mean = 0, sd = 0.4)) 
# exp() because negative values are impossible
require(tidyverse)
df <- tibble(x = x, y = y)
df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x, y)) +
   geom_point() +
   theme_minimal()
```

#### Question

Extracellular enzyme activity is a proxy for the functional abundance of the heterotrophic microbial community in the environmental sample. This entity is comparable to the predator entity in the Lotka-Volterra model. However, in this case the equivalent to the prey entity is missing because substrate dynamics are unobserved.

In the simplest case, we can assume that enzyme activity is only determined by the availability of substrate, more substrate leading to a higher capacity for hydrolysis as manifested in a higher substrate-saturated enzyme activity. In reality, microbial community succession likely plays an important role, but I think I can discount this since I am viewing the dynamic heterotrophic microbial community as a single entity. Therefore I think the simple Lotka-Volterra ODEs outlined above are sufficient.

Is there a way to model the observed change in enzyme activity $N_2$ with time $t$ using $\frac{dN_2}{dt}=N_2(N_1\epsilon\beta-\delta)$ even though $N_1$ in $\frac{dN_1}{dt}=N_1(\alpha-N_2\beta)$ is unobserved? Is it possible to infer changes in unobserved $N_1$ with $t$ from such a hypothetical model? If this is possible, I would be interested in a solution in R and Stan. If this is not possible, I would be interested in an explanation as to why and possible alternatives excluding generalised additive models.